# Filter Articles in a categories based on previously clicked Article in another category.

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla site with a few branches of categories.

One branch of categories is about brands where the Articles are a presentation of a Brand. Example: Brands->European->German->Mercedes(Article).

Another Branch is about Parts and services where an Article represents one part. Example: Parts->Interior->DashBoard->Odometer(Article).

What I need to do is once I click in an Article Inside the Brands category, lets say "Mercedes", and then go to the Parts branch of categories, I need it to display only the Parts (articles) that are related to the Mercedes Articles.

How can I achieve this?

How can I related one Article from one category branch to another article from another category branch?

How can I than use it as a filter in the Parts Category?

I'm considering other ways of doing this, but this is an website that was given to me like this, with hundreds of categories and articles already set that I only need to filter Parts articles according to Brands Articles previously clicked.

Comment: Try using the category or categories module or make a custom module that is more complex, then display the module with the appropriate links.  Or use tags. It's hard to tell without knowing how the parts category is identifying the brand for a given item.  You may want to try [joomla.se].

Comment: I think you should use some module like this   http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/fj-related-articles-plus